# Can i use STDOUT And still loop the script ? (PHP/BATCH)

Tags: php, batch-file

im trying to make a console script with commands in batch with php, 
and i have found this script:

```
for(;;){

fwrite(STDOUT, "\n");
$name = fgets(STDIN);
fwrite(STDOUT, "Hello $name");

sleep(1);
}
```

but it stops on every loop ,
can i make a loop and use this function as well ? 
thanks ..

Comment: This stops on every loop because it's waiting for input from STDIN - is that what you mean?

Comment: What does it mean "stops on every loop?"  Do you get an error?

Comment: yes and i need it to loop and take the command when i write it in ..

Comment: Of course it stops. With each iteration, it's waiting for input from `STDIN`. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: yeh but i want it to loop in background and take command if writen in

Comment: is ther some way around to do this ? 
or do i have to make to diffrent scripts?

Comment: What is it supposed to do if you don't write a command?

Comment: loop my script , 
am trying to make a server in php with command input

Comment: Oh, so you want other things going on, whilst also providing a command prompt?

Comment: yes , it was the plan :P

Comment: Well, that's a lot more complicated, you would either have to poll for keystrokes, rather than using `fgets()` which blocks till a return is pressed; or you would need to thread your program.

Comment: well , im just making it easy and make to separate script,
one for console and one for loop ..
but thanks any way guys :)

Comment: just have to heard if it was possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `stream_select()` to wait for data to appear in the STDIN. The optional timeout value let you go do something else when there is no input. The following code will keep printing "Waiting..." every 200 ms until you enter something:

```
for(;;){
    $read = array(STDIN);
    $write = NULL;
    $except = NULL;
    if(stream_select($read, $write, $except, 0, 200000) > 0) {
        if($read) {
            $name = fgets(STDIN);
            fwrite(STDOUT, "Hello $name");
        }
    } else {
        fwrite(STDOUT, "Waiting...\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try: ignore_user_abort(true);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php

Comment: it was a good try , but it diden work ,
have tryd ini_set('max_execution_time', 1); and set_time_limit(0); but it did not work :/